# Largest Palindrome value made from the product of 2 3-digit numbers

Tags: product, palindrome

```
public static boolean isPal(int value)
{
    String temp = String.valueOf(value);
    int begin=0;
    int end=(temp.length())-1;
    int middle=(begin+end)/2;
    for(int count=begin; count<=middle; count++)
    {
        if(temp.charAt(count)!=temp.charAt(end))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(temp.charAt(count)==temp.charAt(end))
        {
            end--;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static int largestPalindromeNumber()
{
    int largestNumber=0;
    int num1=999;
    int num2=999;
    while(num1>=100 && num2>=100)
    {
        if(isPal(num1*num2))
        {
            largestNumber=num1*num2;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(num1==num2-1)
            {
                num2--;
            }
            else
            {
                num1--;
            }
        }
    }
    return largestNumber;
}
```

When I run this, it returns the palindrome 698896, which is a palindrome, but not the highest palindrome made from the product of two 3 digit numbers. The else statement in the largestPalindrome method basically decrements in this style in order to maintain checking the highest number because 998*998 is greater than 999*997 and so on.

999*999 -> check: 
num1 decrement

998*999 -> check: 
num2 decrement

998*998 -> check

Unfortunately, I am unable to find the correct highest palindrome.

Comment: This is in `Java` right?

Comment: yeah sorry i didnt add that tag i forgot

Comment: Have you tried using System.out.println to see what the values are doing when it runs, to make sure it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your decrement logic will never check values of num1 and num2 that differ by more than 1.  For example, you'll never check 999*997.  You need to do something like:

```
int greatestPal = 0;
for(int num1 = 999; num1 > 99; num1--){
  for(int num2 = 999; num2 > 99; num2--){
    int product = num1 * num2;
    if(isPal(product)){
      greatestPal = Math.max(product, greatestPal);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

In effect, for each value of num1, find the largest num2 that forms a palendrome.  That's the largest palendrome for that iteration of num1.  Then keep track of the greatest one that you find overall.